# Adaptive Cards Templating engine breaks in EXPAND method if string contains escape charector passed as data to rendera

Tags: .net-core, adaptive-cards

When using `Expand` method in AdaptiveCardTemplate engine and if any strings contains escape characters '\' breaks the json parser engine.

***Sample Template file:***

```
var templateJson = {
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "${transactionNo}"
        }
    ]
}
```

***Json Data:***

```
var myTransaction= new
{
    TransactionNo= "Test\\2021\\001"
};
```

***Problematic statement***

```
var templatedResult = new AdaptiveCardTemplate(templateJson);
templatedResult .Expand(myTransaction);
```

Is there a way this can be overturned and avoid engine from breaking.

Comment: I came up against the same issue, did you find an answer? I needed to downgrade from 4.10.0 to 4.9.4 on the Nuget packages Microsoft.Bot.Builder.* I also tried JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(**) that did not work.

Found related bug at https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/4176

Comment: @kevin : No direct answer, i found the issue already raised to Microsoft in github(same as mentioned in your comment).  

As of now I'm manually removing the escape character with "%%" in json before sending it to Template engine, later again replaces the "%%" to "\\" until Microsoft release fix the same.  

The same kind was suggested in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/4176#issuecomment-678114987) also by contributor